# Finding who has access to this shared exchange server mailbox

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

How can I find all the users who are all having access to a shared mail box?

We use a shared mail box in our application, this would be useful to know.

A simple solution will be more useful.

Code to do this in C# is also ok.

Tools from microsoft will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't say what you mean by "having access" so:

```
$mailbox = "foo@example.com"
Get-Mailbox $mailbox | Get-AdPermission
```